# Subquery in Where Clause of LINQ statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

So I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477918/linq-subquery-in) example to have a sub-query in the where clause of this LINQ query.

```
var innerquery =
    from app in context.applications
    select new { app.app_id };

IEnumerable<postDatedCheque> _entityList = context.postDatedCheques
    .Where(e => innerquery.Contains(e.appSancAdvice.application.app_id));
```

The objective was to select those records from *postDatedCheques* that have *app_id* in *applications* table.

But I am getting following erros inside the where clause:

1. Delegate 'System.Func' does not
   take 1 arguments
2. Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not
   a delegate type
3. 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a
   definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload
   'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains(System.Linq.ParallelQuery,
   TSource)' has some invalid arguments
4. Instance argument: cannot convert from
   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
   'System.Linq.ParallelQuery'

What am I coding incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a simple join would do the job. It will filter out the 'cheques' that have no relative 'app':

```
  var _entitylist = 
    from cheque in context.postDatedCheques
    join app in context.applications on cheque.appSancAdvice.application equals app
    select cheque;
```

Edit:

Solutions using a `.Contains(...)` will be translated into a SQL `IN` statement. Which will be very inefficient. Linq `join` is translated into SQL `INNER JOIN` which is very efficient if your DB schema is well trimmed (FKs, index)

Comment: That was a better idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

What about?

```
IEnumerable<postDatedCheque> _entityList = context.postDatedCheques.Where(
     e => context.applications.Any(
          x => e.appSancAdvice.application.app_id == x.app_id));
```

And if you want to use two statements, set the first as an expression function.

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> innerQuery = 
          x => context.applications.Any(y => y.app_id == x);

IEnumerable<postDatedCheque _entityList = 
  context.postDatedCheques.Where(
    x => innerQuery(x.appSancAdvice.application.app_id));
```

Answer (score 2):

`innerquery` is a IQueryable of anonymous type that contains an `app_id`.
The line `Contains(e.appSancAdvice.application.app_id)` doesn't make sense since `e.appSancAdvice.application.app_id` and the anonymous type are not the same type.

Simply do:

```
var _entityList = context.postDatedCheques
                         .Where(e => 
                            context.applications
                                   .Select(a => a.app_id)
                                   .Contains(e.appSancAdvice.application.app_id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
var innerquery =
    from app in context.applications
    select new { app.app_id };

IEnumerable<postDatedCheque> _entityList = context.postDatedCheques
    .Where(e => innerquery.Any(a => a.app_id == e.appSansAdvice.application.app_id));
```

Comment: Should be: `[..] e => innerquery.Any(a => a.app_id == a.appSansAdvice.application.app_id) [..]`