# SQL to LINQ with an IN clause

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

**BACKROUND:**

I have a single table in my database that I use for logging calls to various web services.

Each log entry is linked by a GUID (CorrelationID) that links all log entries for a particular web request.

When searching the logs for a particular piece of data (eg. a persons name) I may get one log entry that has that piece of information, but I want to show all of the log entries related to that same request.

**CURRENTLY:**

To achieve the desired results in SQL I use this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Logging WHERE CorrelationId IN (SELECT DISTINCT CorrelationId FROM Logging WHERE Message like '%fred%') ORDER BY Datetime
```

**PROBLEM:**

I would like to convert this query to LINQ to Entities.

All I have at the moment is the main select

```
var records = db.Loggings.Where(x => x.Datetime >= fromDate && x.Datetime < toDate)
                .Where(x => x.Message.Contains("fred"))
                .OrderBy(x => x.Datetime).AsQueryable();
```

I can't work out the correct syntax for adding the `IN` part.

I have followed other SO answers to similar questions, but still cannot get this to work for my particular scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ subquery IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477918/linq-subquery-in)

Comment: Have you tried making two different queries?

Comment: @Halhex yes, I tried that, it was painfully slow to complete the second query based on the results of the first.

Comment: You are using records twice (records = records).  The entity database is somethings like dbEntity.TableName

Comment: @Bandito Can you show the code you attempted?

Comment: That SQL doesn't even need that `IN`.  You can just use the inner where clause on the outer query and you should get the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the job like this:

```
var subQuery = records.Where(x => x.Datetime >= fromDate && x.Datetime < toDate && x.Message.Contains("fred")).Select(x => x.CorrelationID).Distinct();

var result = records.Where(x => subQuery.Contains(x.CorrelationID)).OrderBy(x => x.Datetime).AsQueryable();
```